# send arabic letter to serial port

Tags: c#

I use datamax printer , I send to serial port by c# software to print arabic in labels

**Code**

```
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.Open();
    //serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
    serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    serialPort1.Write("\x02" + "L" + "\x0D");
    serialPort1.Write("D12" + "\x0D");

    serialPort1.Write("H20" + "\x0D");
    string test_arab = "الحملله";
    serialPort1.Write("190000202600010  " + test_arab + "\x0D");//text
    //serialPort1.Write("B" + test_arab + "\x0D");
    serialPort1.Write("Q" + ' ' + test_arab + "\x0D");
    serialPort1.Write("E" + "\x0D");
    serialPort1.Close();
```

the result in labels like this "???????"

how can i print arabic like "الحمد لله"

Comment: You cannot use Encoding.ASCII, but you already knew that.  Which one you need is going to depend on the printer's character set that you select, 1256 is not terribly likely. You'll have to RTFM or use the telephone.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are using ASCII encoding

```
serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
```

And the source code of C# files are in UTF-8.

So try to convert the string to ascii then write into the port:

```
byte[] pass_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("الحمد لله");
```

Comment: byte[] pass_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("الحمد لله");
            serialPort1.Write("190000202600010  " + "kadkakdakl" +((char)pass_byte[2]).ToString() + "\x0D");

Comment: then what solution ??

Comment: @Mohamed you have to use whatever encoding the printer expects. Try to find that information in the printer's manual. Or just blindly try some encodings that *could* have a chance to work, like UTF8.

Comment: @Mohamed You need to first send a command to the printer to change the current code page (for that find a programmer's manual on the datamax web site for your printer model), then send bytes according to that code page. E.g. [here \[PDF\]](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/fr/en-us/file.cfm/DPL_88-2360-01_B.pdf?contentID=7615&ext=.pdf) they describe supporting Arabic-8, PC-864 Latin/Arabic and Windows Latin/Arabic.